# Replacing '#!' with the '/' symbol in Prestashop module search URL

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop 1.6 module with the search option (actually not done by me). Whenever we click on the search button it will change the URL to http://yourdomain.com/filter#!2017--ABC--Z-400-TT (example). I need this URL to be like http://yourdomain.com/filter/2017--ABC--Z-400-TT. I am able to change the URL but this is leading to the 404 page not found page.

Please anyone have any idea.

Comment: The first url is actually linking to `http://yourdomain.com/filter` the rest of it is an anchor used in javascript with an ajax request. This module is probably meant to be used with ajax only and not direct links

Comment: Is there any way to replace this, without using ajax?

Comment: You should override the module controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite impossible with a module but can be achieved through editing a core file in PrestaShop. You can look at the dispatch() function in DIspatcher.php

The changes are so complex that they cannot be explained here.